# Product space of an open interval and a variable open interval

Tags: general-topology, terminology, product-space

I would like to construct an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the following way. First I construct an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ given by $X=(a,b)$. For every point $x\in X$, I define an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ given by $Y[x]=(f[x], g[x])$ where $f$ and $g$ are smooth functions of $x$. An open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is constructed as $C=\{(x,y)|x\in X, y\in Y[x]\}$. It is clear that $C$ is not a direct product space. I am wondering if there is any special name for this space?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to write $C$ is $\{(x, y) \mid a < x < b, f(x) < y < g(x)\}$. It is the region between the graphs of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ for $x \in (a, b)$. This assumes $f(x) < g(x)$ (otherwise, the interval $(f(x), g(x))$ is empty).

In the following image (taken from [here](http://xaktly.com/AreaBetweenCurves.html)), $C$ is the yellow region. In this example, $a = 1$, $b = 3$, $f(x) = x^2 + 3x + 1$, and $g(x) = x^2+2x+11$.

[image]

It is true that $C$ is not a direct product space *in general*, but it can be a product space (precisely when $f$ and $g$ are constant).

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the diagrammatic representation. To me, this construction appears similar to the concept of bundles where they take a space and attach a vector space to every point of that space. Here, instead of a vector space, I am attaching another open interval. I am wondering if this construction can also be called a vector bundle?

Comment: I want to generalise the construction to higher dimensional spaces. For example, let $X$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$. Let $C$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ obtained by attaching an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to every point of $X$. Is there any special name for $C$?

Comment: It isn't a vector bundle as the fibers of the projection $C \to (a, b)$, $(x, y) \mapsto x$ are not vector spaces. However, $C$ is homeomorphic to the total space of a vector bundle. I am not aware of a special name for $C$. Even in the generalisation you mention, I think the best description for $C$ is the region bounded by the graph of two functions over $X$.